# nanopb - how to specify encoding of integer in proto file

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c, nanopb

How do I set a `int32` to use a fixed size for encoding?

In the [API](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/nanopb/docs/reference.html#pb_type_t), it says

```
PB_LTYPE_FIXED32    0x04    32-bit integer or floating point.
```

But what option do I set in the `.proto` file to encode a `int32` as a `PB_LTYPE_FIXED32` as opposed to a `PB_LTYPE_VARINT`?

In the function `encode_basic_field` the `fields` structure, which is autogenerated, stores the field type which means that this information is set in `.proto` file somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try "int32_t" instead of int32.

please check the "nanopb" project, in the file "nanopb_generator.py", there is   a dictionary called "datatypes", here is some code:

```
    FieldD.TYPE_FIXED32:    ('uint32_t', 'FIXED32',     4,  4),
    FieldD.TYPE_SFIXED32:   ('int32_t',  'SFIXED32',    4,  4),
```

because it's my first time to see the "nanopb" project, I'm not 100% sure whether it will work or not.